# Is there any way to fix ACPI error without kernel patch?

Tags: kernel, freeze, acpi

I have a new notebook which cant load Ubuntu 18.04 kernel without pci=noacpi. Using noacpi it starts normally but produces heat. Is there any workaround for this without kernel modify?

The error message is:

```
     tsc: Refined tsc clocksource calibration:1996.240MHz
     clocksource tsc mask 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles 0x390cac3bdaf, max_idle_ms: 881590646346
     watchdog: BUG: soft lockup -CPU#1 stuck for 22s [migration/1:15]
     ...
     ...
```

With noacpi these things happen:

```
[    0.000000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=16
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 524544, nr_irqs: 272, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.000000] ACPI: Core revision 20170831
[    0.000000] ACPI Error: [MACO] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/dswload-378)
[    0.000000] ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-252)
[    0.000000] ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, (SSDT:ACRPRDCT) while loading table (20170831/tbxfload-228)
[    0.000000] ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 13 successful (20170831/tbxfload-246)
[    0.000000] ACPI: setting ELCR to 0200 (from 0000)
[    0.000000] clocksource: hpet: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 133484873504 ns
[    0.000000] hpet clockevent registered
[    0.000000] APIC: Switch to symmetric I/O mode setup
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: No southbridge IOAPIC found
[    0.000000] AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping
[    0.000000] Switched APIC routing to physical flat.
[    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
[    0.004000] tsc: Detected 1996.367 MHz processor
[    0.004000] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 3992.73 BogoMIPS (lpj=7985468)
```

[kernel load and freeze with acpi[pic]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs6sW.jpg)

Comment: Does this notebook run Windows too? Did watch for an available Bios firmware upgrade?